# ajax request not working in html file running on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, get

I am trying to execute an Http get request using ajax to a python application running on Heroku.

I included the JavaScript in my index.html file.

```
var country = $("#country").val();
var base_url = "https://myapp.herokuapp.com/getCountryStats?country=" + country;


    $("#getDataButton").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url : base_url ,
        type : 'GET',
        dataType:'text',
        success : function(data) {
          alert('Data: '+data);
        },
        error : function(request,error) {
          alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
        }
      });
```

However, my ajax request is just not working as expected.
All the time the error function is executed although the request is processed successfully from the python application running on Heroku.
First I thought it is because I am opening my `index.html` just in a Browser (file://).
So I set up a HTTP server on Localhost and let the HTML file run there. But it is still not working.

When executing the exact same request in Postman it is working absolutely fine.

[Request in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAt7t.png)

I really don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Check your console log, or network log.  You may be getting blocked by CORS.

Comment: Try the following search in your favorite search engine: `ajax works in postman but not on localhost site:stackoverflow.com`

Comment: Just a quick note...


1- Instead of `base_url.concat(country);` you can just do `"https://covid-data-service.herokuapp.com/getCountryStats?country="+country`;



2- why do you declare the datas again in the ajax request? You already have them up there so delete the ones inside the ajax
`

Comment: There are no entries in console log or network log.